# Mongo bulk fetch record based on multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have multiple records stored in mongo collections and I have multiple conditions.
I want to batch or bulk read the records based on different conditions and I also want to know the records which are fetched are outcome of which condition.

I am using spring boot and mongotemplate to perform this operation.

I have tried of following approaches

1.Combining the conditions with OR(But I will not be aware the record is the outcome of which condition.

2.Bulkoperations,But I didnt find bulk read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can combine conditions using $switch or $cond with projection in mongo.Following the is mongo query for the same

```
db.action.aggregate( 
  {
    $project:
      {
        "name":"$name",
        "condNAme" :
        {
          $switch:
            {
              branches: [
              {  case: {$eq: ["$clientId", 1000]}, then:"cond1"},
              {  case: {$eq: ["$clientId", 1001]}, then:"cond2"},
              ],
              default:0
            }
         }
      }
   }
)
```

if first condition is satisfied then it will append cond1,if second condition is satisfied then it will append cond2.So in this way we can identify which condition is executed to true